# Signal Processing in Go

Tags: audio, swig, go, signal-processing

I have come up with an idea for an audio project and it looks like Go is a useful language for implementing it. However, it requires the ability to apply filters to incoming audio, and Go doesn't appear to have any sort of audio processing package. I can use cgo to call C code, but every signal processing library I find uses C++ classes which cgo cannot handle. It looks like libsox may work. Are there any others?

What libsox can provide and what I need is to take an incoming audio stream and divide it into frequency bands. If I can do this while only reading the file once, then bonus! I am not sure if libsox can do this.

Comment: NOTE: There are go bindings for FFTW, so that's something.

Comment: To be honest, if you have any access to Reaktor 5,6, which is often on PC's in music departments, then you can spend 3-5 hours to flesh out your project in reaktor. the filters require one click to bring into the system and it connects them with strings. However, reaktor is only good at pure wave projects, it doesn't cope well with midi and high quality graph outputs. it does have oscilloscopes and 2d color charts only. You can also look at synthmaker if your project is simple. synthmaker is also for robotics. Also check synthesizer API's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a C++ library you could try SWIG, but you'll have to get it out of Subversion. The next release (2.0.1) will be the first released version to support Go. In my experience the Go support is still a little rough, but then again the library I tried to wrap is a monster.

Alternatively, you could still create your own bindings through cgo using the same method SWIG does, but it will be painful and tedious. The basic idea is that you first create a C wrapper, then let cgo create a Go wrapper around your C wrapper.

I don't know anything about signal processing or libsox, though. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I had gotten the impression that callbacks into go from C were not doable at all, but there is a thread about this subject on the go-nuts list at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively new project called [ZikiChombo](https://zikichombo.org)
which contains so far some basic DSP functionality geared toward audio, see [here](https://godoc.org/zikichombo.org/dsp)

The dsp part of the project has filters on its roadmap, but they are not yet there.  On the other hand some infrastructure for implementing filters, such as real fft and block convolution is there.  Meaning that if you want FIRs, and can compute the coefficients by some other means, you can run them via convolution in zc currently with sound in real time.

Basic filtering design support (FIR,Biquad), for example using an ideal filter as a starting point will be the next step for zc.  There are numerous small self-contained open source projects for basic and more advanced FIR and IIR filter design, most notably [Iowa Hills](http://www.iowahills.com) which might be more accessible than a larger project to compute filter coefficients outside of Go.

More advanced filtering such as Butterworth, and filters based on polynomial solving and the bilinear transform will take more time for zc.

There is also some software defined radio Golang projects with some code related to filtering, sorry don't have the links offhand but a search for the topic may lead you to them.

Finally, there is a gonum [Fourier package](https://github.com/gonum/gonum/tree/master/fourier) which also supplies fft.

So Go is growing some interesting and potentially stuff in this domain, but still has quite a ways to go compared to older projects (which are mostly in C/C++, or perhaps with a Python wrapper via numpy for example).

Answer (score 0):

I am using this pure golang repo to perform Fourier Transforms with good effect

https://github.com/mjibson/go-dsp

just supply the FFT call with a

```
import (
    "github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/fft" //  https://github.com/mjibson/go-dsp
)

var audio_wave []float64
// ... now populate audio_wave with your audio PCM samples

var complex_fft []complex128

// input time domain ... output frequency domain of equally spaced freq bins 
complex_fft = fft.FFTReal(audio_wave)
```